# How to download a file from blob and send it has a file response

Tags: python, azure, download, blob

I have a client page which will list all the file in the container, on choosing a file the filename along with the container name is sent to the server.
The server should initiate the file download and should send the file as response to the client request, please refer to the image below:

[image: client download window]

I tried with *get_blob_to_stream*

```
@app.route("/blobs/testDownload/")
def testDownload():
  container_name =request.args.get("containerName")
  print(container_name)
  local_file_name= request.args.get("fileName")

  with BytesIO() as input_blob:
     with BytesIO() as output_blob:
    
    # Download as a stream
        block_blob_service.get_blob_to_stream(container_name, local_file_name, input_blob)
        copyfileobj(input_blob, output_blob)
        newFile = str(output_blob.getvalue())
        with open("file.txt","a") as f:
            f.write(newFile)
            f.close()
        
return send_file('file.txt',attachment_filename='sample.txt',as_attachment=True,mimetype='text/plain')
```

But the file which is getting downloaded is in only text file format, I want to download file irrespective of its format. and I know this is not the right way to download file via Web API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a fixed file-name "file.txt" for all the blobs which may be the reason. Using a stream seems useless here. try get_blob_to_path() instead, check out the following modified code:

--- // your code // ---

> block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path(container_name, local_file_name, **local_file_name**)
>       # notice that I'm reusing the **local_file_name** here, hence no input/output blobs are required
>   return send_file(local_file_name,attachment_filename=local_file_name,as_attachment=True,mimetype='text/plain')

***Complete Code:***

```
@app.route("/blobs/testDownload/")
 def testDownload():
 container_name =request.args.get("containerName")
 print(container_name)
 local_file_name= request.args.get("fileName")

# Download as a file
block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path(container_name, local_file_name, local_file_name)


return send_file(local_file_name,attachment_filename=local_file_name,as_attachment=True,mimetype='text/plain')
```

See if that works!

Answer (score 0):

try not to hard-code the extension, as the extension is part of the blob name, whichever method you are using from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python). Have a look at the method get_blob_to_path as you are downloading the file first locally. The Local file name is the same as the filename in the blob container.

You can try to get the blob.name for each blob file in the container. Blob name contains the file extension(you just have to parse it) which you can use as a parameter for the method above, **and that way you do not have to hard-code it**:
Below you can find an example of how you can iterate through the files in the container and get the blob name, and you can just **adjust it for your use-case**:

```
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=accountName, account_key=accountKey)

# create container if not exists called 'batches'
container_name ='batches'
block_blob_service.create_container(container_name)

# Set the permission so the blobs are public.
block_blob_service.set_container_acl(container_name, public_access=PublicAccess.Container)

# Calculation

blobs = block_blob_service.list_blobs(container_name)

for blob in blobs.items:
    file_name = blob.name
```

So now you can use file_name and split method for '/', and the last item is the filename.extension.